# Postgresql: query to sum date difference between status

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, gaps-and-islands

I have a table to monitor some equipment with a datetime and a status. I would like to calculate the "running days" between "RUN" and "STOP" status.
I try the following request:

```
select run.stamp - 
(
    -- select the first STOP status after the current RUN status
      select stamp 
      from well_monitoring 
      where stamp > run.stamp and status = 'STOP'
      order by stamp limit 1
  )
from well_monitoring run
where
  run.status = 'RUN'
  and ( -- we want only the first RUN
      select status 
      from well_monitoring 
      where stamp < run.stamp 
    order by stamp desc limit 1) <> 'RUN'
order by run.stamp
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3ff0/10) for the table creation / data and test the request.

When I try to SUM to have the total running days:

```
select SUM( run.stamp - ... ) ...
```

I have the following error:

> ERROR: column "run.stamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function Position: 448

So:
- how can I update my query to have the sum ?
- the query have 2 sub queries, is there a better way (cte ?) to do it ?

(Postgres version: 9.1.7)

Comment: Which version of postgres are you running? But would go for CTE...

Comment: In the fiddle all the well_ids are 1. Is that intentional?

Comment: What about something like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3ff0/21 (using CTE)

Comment: I think this is essentially a gaps&islands problem. Added the tag.

Comment: @joop In fact the table have more field, and for my question I should have also remove well_id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your query with:

```
select sum(times) as sum_of_times 
from (

  select run.stamp - 
    (
      -- select the first STOP status after the current RUN status
        select stamp 
        from well_monitoring 
        where stamp > run.stamp and status = 'STOP'
        order by stamp limit 1
    ) times
  from well_monitoring run
  where
    run.status = 'RUN'
    and ( -- we want only the first RUN
        select status 
        from well_monitoring 
        where stamp < run.stamp 
      order by stamp desc limit 1) <> 'RUN'
  order by run.stamp

) alias
```

like in this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3ff0/24).

In this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3ff0/35) you can see how to use CTE in case you want to have all times and sum of times in one result set.

Comment: This answer is terrible, even the result is incorrect. Sorry, I had to downvote. I seldomly do.

Comment: I feel honored, but *terrible* is not a constructive evaluation. Why do you think the result is incorrect?

Comment: Maybe because the result turns out to be *negative* ? (it does answer the initial question, though: how to fix this ...)

Comment: Both standard SQL and Postgres allow negative intervals. Do you think positive intervals are nice and negative are terrible? The question did not relate to this issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with negative intervals. Though, IMHO the OP wants to measusure the accumulated amount of time spent in all the intervals. Positive. (or: in forward direction)

Comment: I do not see any clues supporting your opinion. The main OP question is: "how can I **update my query** to have the sum?"

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be simplified a bit, but it works (Note it does note need window functions, so it could be adapted to any SQL implementation)

```
SELECT one.id , one.stamp, one.status
        , two.id, two.stamp, two.status
        , (two.stamp - one.stamp) AS diff
FROM well_monitoring one
JOIN well_monitoring two ON two.well_id = one.well_id
        AND two.stamp > one.stamp
        AND two.status = 'STOP'
        -- find the first STOP:
        -- there should be on other STOP
        -- between one: RUN
        --     and two: STOP
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM well_monitoring x
                WHERE x.well_id = one.well_id
                AND x.stamp > one.stamp
                AND x.stamp < two.stamp
                AND x.status = 'STOP'
                )
WHERE one.status = 'RUN'
        -- If there are consecutive RUNs
        -- (without an intervening STOP)
        -- one should be the first RUN
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM well_monitoring x
        WHERE x.well_id = one.well_id
        AND x.status = 'RUN'
        AND x.stamp < one.stamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM well_monitoring xx
                WHERE xx.well_id = x.well_id
                AND xx.stamp > x.stamp
                AND xx.stamp < one.stamp
                AND xx.status <> 'RUN'
                )
        )
        ;
```

Adding the aggregation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This does about the same as @joop's answer, but using window functions to do the edge-detection. Note that the rank+not exists() is needed to pair the stop events to their nearest start events.

```
WITH edges AS (
        SELECT id AS this_id
        , status AS this_status
        , well_id AS well_id
        , LAG(status) over ww AS prev_status
        , dense_rank() over ww AS rnk
        FROM well_monitoring
        WINDOW ww AS (partition by well_id ORDER BY stamp)
        )
, starters AS (
        SELECT this_id, well_id, rnk
        FROM edges
        WHERE this_status = 'RUN'
        AND COALESCE(prev_status, 'OMG') <> 'RUN'
        )
, stoppers AS (
        SELECT this_id, well_id, rnk
        FROM edges
        WHERE prev_status = 'RUN'
        AND this_status <> 'RUN'
        )
SELECT m0.well_id
        , SUM(m1.stamp - m0.stamp)::interval AS duration
FROM starters s0
JOIN stoppers s1 ON s1.well_id = s0.well_id
        AND s1.rnk > s0.rnk
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM stoppers nx
                WHERE nx.well_id = s0.well_id
                AND nx.rnk > s0.rnk AND nx.rnk < s1.rnk
                )
JOIN well_monitoring m0 ON m0.id = s0.this_id
JOIN well_monitoring m1 ON m1.id = s1.this_id
GROUP BY m0.well_id
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
 well_id |     duration      
---------+-------------------
       1 | 320 days 64:28:00
(1 row)
```

(I suspect the 64 hours is a bug ...)